# CF query remove empty string results for total sum

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to fix my query so that my total sum column will equal the correct number. I tried changing this line `<cfset columnSum = ArraySum(allLocCode['locationCount'])>` to `<cfset columnSum = ArraySum(trim(allLocCode['locationCount']))>` But it through an error. I want the empty string like in the picture below to not be counted for the total just like it does not show in the table. Is there another way to pull off this trim for my total column?

```
<cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry> 
    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT *
        FROM cl_checklists
    </cfquery>

    <cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry> 

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Percent of Total Checklists</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location Total</strong></th> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfquery name="allLocCode" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT trans_location, COUNT(*) AS locationCount FROM GetLocationInfo GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location 
    </cfquery>
     <cfloop query="allLocCode">
      <cfset thisLocationName = trim(allLocCode.trans_location) />

      <cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry" dbtype="query">
          SELECT trans_location,count(*) AS locCntr FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location='#thisLocationName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
      </cfquery>
      <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
        <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr/allLocCode.locationCount) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
        <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
      </tr>
     </cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
        <cfset columnSum = ArraySum(allLocCode['locationCount'])>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><cfoutput>#columnSum#</cfoutput></td>
      <cfdump var="#allLocCode#">
      <cfdump var="#allLocCodeForLocationQry#">
      <cfdump var="#thisLocationName#">
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!--- Total of All Sum of each column --->
</table>
```

[image]

The correct answer should reflect 334 not 340

Comment: Couldn't this be fixed by editing your first query, `allLocCode` to only return rows where the TRANS_LOCATION column isn't blank or empty? Currently it has no WHERE clause.

Comment: Free points are fun, but I usually only collect on answers I'm confident in at the time of posting. My comment was a happy accident. Glad it helped!

Comment: In your example they are all at 100% so I'm guessing you mean the average percentage? You would put all the percentages in a list or array, just like you did with the location count, then divide that by the recordcount of the relevant query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here's an answer with the relevant code isolated:

```
<cfquery name="allLocCode" dbtype="query"> 
SELECT DISTINCT trans_location, COUNT(*) AS locationCount 
FROM GetLocationInfo 
WHERE trans_location is not null 
GROUP BY trans_location 
ORDER BY trans_location 
</cfquery>
```

If you need more help with the percentage stuff I'd recommend starting a new post. I see from your history you already have several threads kind of related to this feature, and as it gets more complicated it'll help to separate everything.